# Processing flat file using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have to process a flat file that contains lists of codes and sub codes. For example

CodeA

SubCodeA1

SubCodeA2

CodeB

SubCodeB1

SubCodeB2

Basically I need to map these two separate code lists Code Lists A and B to two separate tables using SSIS.

Using ssis to relate each code to sub-code is a bit awkward. ssis is handy when I want to filter each Code or sub code separately but there is no easy way to relate each code to its sub codes without using a script component. If I'm using a script component would it be better to use a pure .net solution? Any thoughts? Or have I missed something obvious in the toolbox that would do the trick for this problem?

Comment: What does "Relate" mean? How do you implement relationship? Being in the same row is already a relationship.

Comment: sorry all codes are on separate lines? ie line 1 contains Code A, line 2 contains SubCodeA1 etc

Comment: You gave example where line 1 has code A related sub codes only. Same for code B. Otherwise please provide more relevant example.

Answer (score 0):

I would load this data into a SQL table which has an addition column with datatype = Integer and Identity set.  This will give you an incrementing row number for each row.

Then I would write a complex SQL query to split the data as required, e.g. for the Code B rows:

`SELECT * FROM Staging_Table WHERE Identity_Column < (
SELECT Identity_Column FROM Staging_Table WHERE Generic_Column = 'CodeB' )`